# Why decrypting Persian text in AES256 remove some characters from the end?

Tags: c#, encryption

Want to encrypt and decrypt Persian text in C# (.net framework 8) it works fine in English alphabets but when I use Persian/Arabic text, some characters have been removed from the end of the result, what's wrong with my codes?

```
public class AES256
{
    private static RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged;
    private static byte[] key, pwd, ivBytes, iv;
    private enum EncryptMode { ENCRYPT, DECRYPT };

    public static string Encrypt(string _plainText, string _key, string _initVector)
    {
        InitAES256();
        return Process(_plainText, _key, EncryptMode.ENCRYPT, _initVector);
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string _encryptedText, string _key, string _initVector)
    {
        InitAES256();
        return Process(_encryptedText, _key, EncryptMode.DECRYPT, _initVector);
    }

    private static void InitAES256()
    {
        rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged();
        rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijndaelManaged.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
        rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
        key = new byte[32];
        iv = new byte[rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8]; 
        ivBytes = new byte[16];
    }

    private static string Process(string _inputText, string _encryptionKey, EncryptMode _mode, string _initVector)
    {
        string _out = string.Empty;


        pwd = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_encryptionKey);
        ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_initVector);

        int len = pwd.Length;
        if (len > key.Length)
        {
            len = key.Length;
        }
        int ivLenth = ivBytes.Length;
        if (ivLenth > iv.Length)
        {
            ivLenth = iv.Length;
        }

        Array.Copy(pwd, key, len);
        Array.Copy(ivBytes, iv, ivLenth);

        rijndaelManaged.Key = key;
        rijndaelManaged.IV = iv;


        if (_mode.Equals(EncryptMode.ENCRYPT))
        {
            byte[] plainText = rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_inputText), 0, _inputText.Length);
            _out = Convert.ToBase64String(plainText);
        }
        else if (_mode.Equals(EncryptMode.DECRYPT))
        {
            byte[] plainText = rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(Convert.FromBase64String(_inputText), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(_inputText).Length);
            _out = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
        }
        rijndaelManaged.Dispose();

        return _out;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
string initVector = "123";
string SyncGetKey = "2587";
string result = AES256.Encrypt("داود", SyncGetKey, initVector);
result = AES256.Decrypt(h, SyncGetKey, initVector);
```

The result is **"دا"** and **"ود"** has been removed from the end (as an example).

Comment: Please don't reuse cipher implementations, especially not in static code. The design of the class and the implementation is pretty horrid. Decode base 64 again just to get to the size? But besides that, it is extremely likely that the encoding / decoding problem takes place before it ever enters the cipher (e.g. due to how the source code is stored), check the plaintext length in bytes! Hint: don't use RijndaelManaged, use `Aes.Create()` so you can use hardware AES acceleration instead of .NET libs.

Comment: The bug is in the `EncryptMode.ENCRYPT` part. There the plaintext size is determined incorrectly. Instead of `_inputText.Length` it must be `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_inputText).Length`.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks, you have right, plz write it as the answer